# How to show how many factorial numbers in python with while loop

Tags: python

i need help.

How to show how many numbers in one factorials with python programs?

for the example:
factorial: 12
1
2
3
5
6
12
total factorial: 6.

can someone help me with input and while loop? Thanks (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Can you please clarify it more ?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: If you have specific issues while solving this yourself you can ask here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including sample input, sample output, and code for what you've tried so far

Comment: how do you get the number 6 from this set of numbers? `12 1 2 3 5 6 12` If you tell us that and what you've tried, we would be able to help you better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you wanted to ask was the factors of a given number.

you can achieve that simply as follows.

```
def factors(x):
   count = 0
   for i in range(1, x + 1):
       if x % i == 0:
           print(i)
           count = count + 1
   print 'Total factors:', count
```

```
>>> factors(12)
1
2
3
4
6
12
Total factors: 6
```